# Converting Rails 2 app with ActiveMessaging to Rails 3, have a few questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activemessaging

I'm currently converting a fairly large Rails 2 app to Rails 3.  The app uses activemessaging in its plugin form.  It's used with Amazon SQS primarily for file uploads, among a few other things.  I have the all the queues I use defined in messaging.rb and there are existing processors to handle messages.  In the Rails 3 version I'm switching over to the activemesssaging gem, version 0.9.0.  Aside from getting rid of the old plugin version is there much else I need to do to my existing messaging.rb and processors?  Also right now I manually start the poller script, is that the same?  I can't seem to find much info about Rails 3 and activemessaging so if anyone can give me the basic steps of what I need to do it would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't remember there being a big difference with using the gem - I did not change the way messaging.rb or broker.yml are loaded, and you still have to start the poller yourself.

In general there is not a big difference with Rails 3, which is why you aren't seeing much about it.

Comment: On 3.2, I had issues with the ApplicationProcessor being in the file application.rb, so I'll be updating that to application_processor.rb at some point soon - let me know if you hit that.